# Epoch time to date/time format in boost c++

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

In Linux, i am reading epoch time from "/proc/stat" as btime and i want to convert to readable date and time format with c++ boost.

I have tried below things and date is working properly.

```
    time_t btime_ = 1505790902; //This is epoch time read from "/proc/stat" file.

    std::wstring currentDate_ = L"";
    boost::gregorian::date current_date_ = 
             boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_).date();

    std::wstring year_ = boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>
                                         (current_date_.year());
    std::wstring day_ = boost::lexical_cast<std::wstring>
                                         (current_date_.day());
```

Here i am getting correct year and day. BUT How can i get time( HH::MM:SS) from above epoch time ? Let me give hint - i can try.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6a75c9d7a0b2f6a)</kbd>**

```
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>

int main() {
    std::time_t btime_ = 1505790902; //This is epoch time read from "/proc/stat" file.

    std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_) << "\n";

    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%H:%M:%S")));
    std::cout << boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_) << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
2017-Sep-19 03:15:02
03:15:02
```

### UPDATE

To the comment:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99be80d809161d2f)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/c_local_time_adjustor.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
namespace g  = boost::gregorian;
using local_adj = boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor<pt::ptime>;

int main() {
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new pt::time_facet("%H:%M:%S")));

    std::time_t btime_ = 1505790902; // This is epoch time read from "/proc/stat" file.

    pt::ptime const timestamp = pt::from_time_t(btime_);

    std::cout << timestamp << "\n";

    // This local adjustor depends on the machine TZ settings
    std::cout << local_adj::utc_to_local(timestamp) << " local time\n";
}
```

Prints

```
+ TZ=CEST
+ ./a.out
03:15:02
03:15:02 local time
+ TZ=MST
+ ./a.out
03:15:02
20:15:02 local time
```

Comment: Thanks. it is useful. Now I have one question. here we get the time (03:15:02) in UTC. Can we get this time depending on system timezone ?

Comment: @Neel That's unrelated. I just nicked the sample from [the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.local_utc_conversion) and updated my answer. See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99be80d809161d2f)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `time_facet`. Here's an example that prints UTC date/time:

```
std::string PrintDateTime()
{
    std::stringstream str;
    boost::posix_time::time_facet *facet = new boost::posix_time::time_facet("%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S-UTC");
    str.imbue(std::locale(str.getloc(), facet));
    str << boost::posix_time::second_clock::universal_time(); //your time point goes here
    return str.str();
}
```

Notice that you don't need  to worry about the memory management of `facet`. It's taken care of already from within boost.

Comment: Here, epoch time is getting used. Can you please suggest how can i use "btime_" and get time in HH:MM:SS ?

Comment: You just have to put the object `boost::posix_time::from_time_t(btime_)` in the place where I made a comment in the code.